# Dimmer buzzing, lights flickering

Tags: led, dimmer, dimming, lighting

Got an issue with my lights and a dimmer. I got a room with 4 lights in it (6W LED panel lights) and a 60-600W dimmer. Somewhy, the lights from time to time flicker and the dimmer is buzzing all the time, which is quite annoying. Googling suggested that this is usually caused by overloading the dimmer, but with 4 x 6W lights, I'm not that sure that is the issue.

Saved some images to Imgur as well, maybe someone from you can help me with this issue. Bought the apartment which had these in (should've been brand new as well).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEtoQ.jpg

Best regards

Comment: I had this too. Apparently the dimmer is not compatible with the LEDs. I tried others, and the issue was different - on the minimum setting of the dimmer the LED was still glowing faintly. So it's the dimmer. It's just not good for LEDs, get another one.

Comment: The CC LED driver has a wide input V range so it is not meant to be dimmable. and they spelt *Madel* wrong. However they do have dimmable parabolic LEDs

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 there are special dimmable LEDs on the market.

Comment: Yes I use them..

Comment: @Tony noticed the Madel as well, so it's the driver which isn't compatible and should be replaced, right?

Comment: right...CC driver is not the right approach.  Rather a Buck regulator (ratiometric) with a current limit.

Comment: You are most likley not consuming minimum load required by the dimmer. Can you try to add one incandescent in parallel, or replace one of the LEDs with a normal halogen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the converter has a wide input range like 85~265Vac then it is intended to be CC over all international voltage tolerances and not dimmable without stress and noise.  This input range is 265/85 = 3.1

If the converter has a reduced input range with CC like 185~265Vac with a Max/min ratio of 1.4 then it will start to dim when the input is below 185 and less likely to be over-stressed by pulse currents pinging the coils and surge currents on caps.  But this is no guarantee they designed it correctly for dimming, but may advertise as such. ( cheap on Ebay)

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the answer! As I'm not that clever in electronics, wanted to ask you, what is your proposition what should I do. I've thought about replacing the dimmers to regular switches, but I'd like to have at least one room with a dimmer. At first I thought it's the dimmer (as the dimming works, just the buzzing and the flickering is annoying). What should I do and how should I proceed? Should I buy some better LED drivers (do you recommend any)? Best regards!

Comment: Get a dimmable bulb that matches your needs. Lots out there now,

Answer (score 1):

The driver is not compatible with dimming. You may be able to replace it with a driver that IS compatible. Meanwell makes LED drivers (HLG series) that have dimming input leads. You can get them through Digikey or Arrow and many other sites.

Comment: Hi Norm, thanks for the answer! So if the dimmer is buzzing but lights are dimming (with flickering from time to time), then that means that the drivers are bad? What kind of a driver would you recommend for the lights? Best regards!

Comment: It does not mean the driver is bad, its just trying to function outside of it normal operating parameters. I would look at Meanwell's LPF series of drivers, since you wattage is so low - the smallest one they have is 16 watts, which could run 2 of your 6 watt lights. It has a set of extra wires that you can attach a potentiometer to for the dimming function. Just google for "LPF LED driver".